# Cannot read property 'isDirectory' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

This demo code is illustrated in the book named *SMASHING Node.js:Javascript Everywhere*. However, when I typed `node index` in the command line, it prompted me that

> Cannot read property 'isDirectory' of undefined.

I wonder how to solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are not inspecting for an error within the callback given to `fs.stat`, which is indicated by the presence of `err`. It is likely that an error is occurring and `stat` is therefore `undefined`. Try looking for an error before acting on `stat`:

```
fs.stat(__dirname + '/' + filename, function (err, stat) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    // ...
});
```